# How to add categorical variable to continuous when doing Linear Regression in Python?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

If I have independent cts variables [x1, x2, x3] and categorical variable [x4] which can be categorized into [x4_1, x4_2] for dummy variable 0/1
If I fit linear regression in sklearn
it will give me something like this:

```
y = intercept + a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x4_1 + e_x4_2
```

Supposed i want to add an interaction term like x1*x4_1 so that the model is this:

```
y = intercept + a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x4_1 + e_x4_2 + f*x1*x4_1
```

Im doing the Linear regression without using the OLS function from the statsmodel. So i have to create a new column in my dataframe. My question is, since there are zeros in the categorical column once i have converted it to dummy variables, is possible to do that? If not how to add interaction terms in my regression model?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What's wrong with multiplying by zero?

Comment: Will the column have zeroes and the other 1× the rest of the column? I assumed it did not make sense

Comment: That’s exactly what will happen, and that’s the behavior we want. By doing that, we get an estimate for the slope of group $0$ and then and estimate of the slope for group $1$ by adding the value of the interaction parameter to the estimate for group $0$. (This probably won’t make sense at first, but try to reason through the algebra in a simple setting with one continuous feature, a binary feature, and an interaction.)

Comment: Thank you @Dave